# python pandas sort_values with multiple custom keys

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, I would like to sort column `A` ascending, and `B` ascending but using the absolute value. How do I do this? I tried like `df.sort_values(by=['A', 'B'], key=lambda x: abs(x))` but it will take the absolute value of both columns and sort ascend.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,-3], 'B': [-1, 2, -3]})
```

output:

```
    A   B
0   1   -1
1   2   2
2   -3  -3
```

Expected output:

```
    A   B
0   -3  -1
1   1   2
2   2   -3
```

Comment: So you want to sort the columns separately? because in your expected output. -3 in column A is not same row than the -3 in column B like in the input

Comment: the output that I posted is sorted using `df.sort_values(by=['A', 'B'], key=lambda x: abs(x))`

Comment: so what you call output, is actually `df` and `df.sort_values(by=['A', 'B'], key=lambda x: abs(x))` yes. what I'm saying is in your expected output, the value -3 in column A is not same row than the -3 in column B like in the input. Using `sort_values` does not misalign values between columns. SO you want to sort the values in column A with ascending order and sort the absolute of B in ascending order separately to get the expecting result?

Comment: @sammywemmy. It's not possible. The index is common to all columns and can't be dissociated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple sort key because index can't be dissociated. The only way is to sort your columns independently and recreate a dataframe:

```
>>> df.agg({'A': lambda x: x.sort_values().values,
            'B': lambda x: x.sort_values(key=abs).values}) \
      .apply(pd.Series).T

   A  B
0 -3 -1
1  1  2
2  2 -3
```

Comment: Brilliant. Spend several hours trying to figure out why only one column was sorted for me even though `sort_values()`  accepts multiple columns to `by` argument: `sort_values(by=['calories', 'fat', 'carbs', 'protein'], ascending=[False, False, False, False])`. Every time, only the first column was actually sorted. Now it makes more sense but also confusing why there's such an option :-) Anyway, during research haven't seen anyone mention what you wrote about "*sort your columns independently and recreate a dataframe*". Grateful for your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy.sort, to so sort column A values

```
df =df.assign(A= np.sort(df['A'].values))



   A  B
0 -3 -1
1  1  2
2  2 -3
```